# asp c# login with connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, db2

I can't seem to find any helpful articles of what I'm trying to achieve so I'm assuming I'm approaching it incorrectly.  I'm building a web application working with an ibm db2 database.  Currently I have the following connection string in my web.config file:

```
<add name="AS400ConnectionString" connectionString="DATASOURCE=myDataSource;USER ID=userID;PASSWORD=password;DefaultCollection=collection;DataCompression=True;" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries"/>
```

and it works just fine with a statically entered userID and password and will allow me to login.  My question is how do I get this to work with a dynamic username and password since this application will have a login page where they will enter their username and password?

Edit:

I can get it to work how I want using this code on my code behind page:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        //connection string for database
        string constr = "DATASOURCE=source;USERID=" + Login1.UserName.ToString() + ";PASSWORD=" + Login1.Password.ToString() + ";DefaultCollection=collection;DataCompression=True;";

        try
        {
            //Clears failure text if any
            Login1.FailureText = "";

            //connects to database
            using(iDB2Connection myConnection = new iDB2Connection())
            {


                Session["username"] = Login1.UserName.ToString();

                //Authenticates user and sends to default landing page
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
            }


            //Sends user to login landing page
            Response.Redirect("~/MemberPages/Warranty.aspx"); 
        }
        catch (iDB2Exception er)
        {
            //Displays login errors
            ValidationSummary1.ValidationGroup = Login1.UniqueID;

            //Displays login errors from AS400
            Login1.FailureText = er.MessageDetails.ToString();
        }
```

But then I guess where I get confused is when I get redirected successfully to my landing page how do I then continue to query the database with that users credentials?  Or is that when I should start using the previously listed connection string in my web.config file?

Comment: Maybe by creating a form to collect username and password and then a method to authenticate with same?

Comment: I think you might be confusing some concepts here. 

This is a valid connection string for the DB when you want your web app to access the server. 

If you want your users to be able to login using their own credentials you'll need to do a little more and it'll depend on the web stack you'll use.

Asumming you're using asp.net (as per the tag in the question) you'll need a provider.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yes I'm definitely confusing some concepts.  I made some edits if that adds any clarification and then you could point me in the right direction possibly.